# How to harvest Azure Web App For Containers webhook

Tags: azure, web-applications, containers

I wish to bind the web app update & warm start to the Azure container registry image using the web app's container webhook URL. I can find the Azure CLI command for creating the webhook push in the ACR, but haven't yet found how to query the web app.
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to query the web app?

Comment: The web app webhook url is one of the inputs when creating the push notification in the Azure ACR webhook. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
az webapp deployment container config -n sname -g rgname -e true
```

from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/app-service-linux-cli